# Dynamic help command discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord bot but I have an issue. I'm still quite new to discord.js and node.js. This is my code:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
 function getMenu() {
  var hpmenu = {};
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   dashboard.readServerBoundValue(
    `${message.guild.id}`,
    'PREFIX',
    async function(output) {
     if (output) {
      var prefixxx = output;
     } else {
      var prefixxx = config.botPrefix;
     }
     //=====================================================================================================
     fs.readdir('./src/commands/', (err2, files2) => {
      files2.forEach((f2, i2) => {
       hpmenu[f2] = new discord.MessageEmbed();
       hpmenu[f2].setTitle(`${f2}`);
       console.log('Added catagory ' + f2);
       //=========================================================================================
       fs.readdir(`./src/commands/${f2}`, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach((f, i) => {
         const cmd = f.replace('.js', '');
         hpmenu[f2].addField(cmd, 'test');
         console.log('Added command ' + cmd);
         //=====================================================================================================
        });
        resolve(hpmenu);
       });
      });
     });
    }
   );
  });
 }

 async function main() {
  var output = await getMenu();
  message.channel.send(output['developer']);
 }
 main();
};
```

This code doesnt have any errors but this is the issue I'm having:

[image: the issuse]

The issue is that it runs the main function before it finished the `getMenu` function.
How to solve this? I have read multiple posts about this. Thanks for reading everyone!

Answer (score 0):

After alot of coding i reached my goal; Making a dynamic help menu with pagination.
This is the code:

https://pastebin.com/QGVfutti

It functions good. The only thing you need is to make a file named config.json in the root directory of the bot where index.js is located and add a key named "embedColor" put your commands in

> ./src/commands/CATAGORY/COMMAND.js

and this is the result:

[image]

sorry for bad english. Do note if you use it you still have to implement the prefix and description yourself this depends per command handler and database engine.
You can change the description code and the command name at line 19 in the pastebin. if you want a image you can add a new line after line 13:

```
hmu[i].setImage("IMAGE");
```

Its just a discord embed and it will work fine, add thumbnails, authors, and change however you like. You do not have to credit me if you're using it

Sorry for my bad english and a thank you to Lioness100 for editing the text. English is not my first language :) Have a nice day everyone bye!